# Can't install Realtek drivers (rtl8821ce)

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, wifi, drivers, realtek

Output of `lspci`: `02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter`

Link: https://github.com/k82cn/rtl8821ce.
I cloned it, and used `make && make install`.(it compiled successfuly)

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What is the issue? Did you get an error when loading the module (please post the error)? Did you get an error when running `make install` (because you should have used `sudo make install`)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by turning Secure Boot off in the BIOS.